# How to restrict access to dashboards by user/group permissions?

Tags: sonarqube

We develop software for different customers and use a single instance sonarqube. We have created one dashboard per customer which contains all its projects.

Up to now just our developers used the system and everything was fine.

Now we would like to give our customers access to sonarqube so they can see their projects state.

We put the customer users in diffrent groups and restricted access to the projects by group. So each customer can only see his projects. Still fine.

But we did not find a way to restrict access to the dashboards. So each customer can see the list of alle available dashboards. This contains the list of all our other customers. How bad! Just to make it clear: For a customer user the list of projects of all dashboards except its own company dashboard will be empty - he just sees the names of the other customer, which is still to much.

So is there any solution to configure dashboard visibility by users/groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do confirm that this is not possible to share a dashboard only with some users or groups. When sharing a dashboard, you share it with all users.

Comment: Ok. So we un-shared all shared dashboards which contained customer or product names. Little quirk: All users who already shared a dashboard will still see it, although not shared any more. Security risk: Users can guess dashboard id and manipulate follow-request. So they can follow dashboards which are **not** shared.

Comment: Which version of SonarQube are you using @HorstKrause ? Thanks

Comment: version 4.3.2 @Freddy Mallet

Comment: Thanks @HorstKrause and I do confirm that this security flaw doesn't exist anymore in the 4.5.4 LTS version.